# Twitter OAuth Error via Akamai Edge

Tags: twitter, oauth, akamai

After I put my domain under Akamai Edge, my previously working Twitter Connect flow stopped working and users get a login error.
Debugging, I found my OAuth call to [this url](https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml) answers "Bad Authentication data".

I tried to look over the net for solutions but it seems I'm the only one with this problem, thanks in advance to everyone who will try to help me.

Comment: You should include your code that makes the OAuth call, with the credentials scrubbed out.

Answer (score 0):

Just undo the recent changes you've made if the Twitter Client was running smoothly earlier. you must have messed up somewhere!

Comment: Yes, if I remove akamai from the whole site it works again, but I wondering if there's a way to let the connect work with Akamai Edge on.